# How to limit JavaScript API Request Decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below code to fetch some data from an api.  The response will always be a number however I want to limit the number of decimal places to 2 when I output this.

```
  $(document).ready(function sendRequest() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://apiurl',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(response) {
            $("#test").html(response);
          },
          error: function() {
            $('#errors').text("Error");
          }
        });
    });
```

I tried the below but this doesn't work.

```
$("#test").html(response.toFixed(2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why doesn’t it work? Does it throw an error? It’s also incorrect syntax, but I don’t know if that is a typo

Comment: `$("#test").text((+response).toFixed(2))` ... because you must first convert the string to a number (with unary `+`).

Comment: `response` will be a string. You need to convert it to an integer/float first

Comment: We would need to see an example of your response..  But either way, im sure your response is a `string`, so you'll need to parse the string or convert it to number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response variable is string you need to convert your variable first

```
var res = parseFloat(response) ;

$("#test").html(res.toFixed(2)) ;
```